# Split quotients of number into array javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I need to split or divide specific value in 3 part in jQuery but result should not be in decimal.

Let me share an example :

```
$800 / 3 
Result  $267, $267, and $266
```

I need a function or logic in jQuery or Javascript.

Thanks in advance

I tried round function of jQuery but it's increased the total value.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) function always rounds down and returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

[`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

```js
console.log(Math.floor(266.66));
console.log(Math.round(266.66));
```

By there, you can create a function to get and array of quotients by looping and checking if the total sum of quotients exceeds to the dividend

```js
let result = getQoutientsArray(800, 3);
let result3 = getQoutientsArray(1600, 6);
let result2 = getQoutientsArray(700, 4);



console.log(result);
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)


function getQoutientsArray(num, divisor) {
  let answers = [];

  for (x = 0; x < divisor; x++) {
    let sum = answers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    let qoutient = Math.round(num / divisor);

    let remaining = divisor - answers.length;
    let remaininganswer = (remaining-1) * Math.floor(num / divisor);

    if (sum + qoutient + remaininganswer <= num) {
      answers.push(qoutient);
    } else {
      answers.push(Math.floor(num / divisor));
    }
  }

  return answers;
}
```